# Class NmeaGpsDriver in AndroidThings

Tags: android-things

I don't find the class NmeaGpsDriver in any androidthings: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.things/androidthings
Do you have a jar? or what class I cound used instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That class is an extension of the built in GNSS driver. It's in fact available as one of the provided [sample drivers](https://github.com/androidthings/contrib-drivers/tree/master/gps/src/main/java/com/google/android/things/contrib/driver/gps) on GitHub.

You can import it with:
`implementation 'com.google.android.things.contrib:driver-gps:1.0'`

Comment: If you are not using Grandle, there is a jar of this GNSS driver to add?

Comment: Yeah everything is hosted on [JCenter](https://bintray.com/google/androidthings/contrib-driver-gps/1.0#files/com%2Fgoogle%2Fandroid%2Fthings%2Fcontrib%2Fdriver-gps%2F1.0)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't find the download link

Comment: Files > 1.0 > driver-gps-1.0-sources.jar